# Invoke-Command access to share for is not working for 1 machines out of 5

Tags: powershell-3.0

Honestly i don't even know where to start with this.  I'm a little baffled and i think the issue has to do with the client machine, but i'm not sure what.

I am also NOT a powershell master in the least.  Here's the deal.

**Original goal:**
Run invoke-command from Machine A to Machine B with specific credentials.  The command running is a powershell command on Machine B that refers to file that lives on a share in Machine A.

**note:**  I have this similarly working on Win 10 to Win 10 and Win 10 to 2019core. The issue shows up on a Win 10 to 2016 (Desktop experience), the file that is being referred lives on the win 10 machine.

I have attempted to use the raw command directly to the remote machine as well as copy a script to machine B to run locally.

**worth noting:** If, on Machine B you can run the above noted script and point the the same share on Machine A, all it works no problem.

```
$Username_srv = '.\Administrator'
$Password_srv = '********'
$pass_srv = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password_srv -Force
$Cred_srv = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username_srv, $pass_srv

Invoke-Command -ComputerName <MachineB> -Credential $Cred_srv -ScriptBlock{
    powershell.exe C:\HCK_execution.ps1 -PDEF "\\<MACHINEA>\PDEF_XML\CsDeviceControl\DC_Win10_Pro_x64_PDEF_SINGLE_TEST.xml"
    }
```

I have:

- Enabled Winrm and ensured trustedhosts was * (catchall)
- Added the user to the share host machine
- Changed permissions on the directories and added users and admin group

ERROR:

```
PDEF Locaiton: \\<MachineA>\PDEF_XML\CsDeviceControl\DC_Win10_Pro_x64_PDEF_SINGLE_TEST.xml
Logging directory: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\HCK Execution Engine\2019-01-03T07-50-14-49
Information: Program: HCK Execution engine launched.
Information: Action: 
Using project definition file: \\<MachineA>\PDEF_XML\CsDeviceControl\DC_Win10_Pro_x64_PDEF_SINGLE_TEST.xml

Information: Parse: 
Parse project definition file.
Load project definition file: \\<MachineA>\PDEF_XML\CsDeviceControl\DC_Win10_Pro_x64_PDEF_SINGLE_TEST.xml

Error: Program: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\\<MachineA>\PDEF_XML\CsDeviceControl\DC_Win10_Pro_x64_PDEF_SINGLE_TEST.xml' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boo
lean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrlDelegate(Object xmlResolver)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.CompressedStack.Run(CompressedStack compressedStack, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.Certification.ProjectClient.LoadDefinitionFile(String projectDefinitionFile)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.Certification.Parse.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.Certification.Program.Main(String[] args)
Information: Program: HCK Execution engine completed.
Log saved to: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\HCK Execution Engine\2019-01-03T07-50-14-49\hckexecutionengine.log
```

I really thought since I know copying the ps1 file over and running locally a call to the machine all works, that that would get me where i needed to go.

I know that double-hops aren't allowed in invoke-commands, but since this has been working on multiple other machines i figured as long as the machine can access the share there would be no need for a double hop in authentication.

This issue feels specific to the server machine and a config, i just can't figure it out.

Any help would be great.  Honestly i'm not sure what's helpful to provide seeing as i'm not doing anything really fancy here, and i have this working on other machines with another share.

RUNNING DIRECT ON THE MACHINE, USING DEFAULTS

```
PS C:\> .\HCK_execution.ps1
PDEF Locaiton: \\<MachineA>\PDEF_XML\CsDeviceControl\DC_Win10_Pro_x64_PDEF_SINGLE_TEST.xml
Logging directory: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\HCK Execution Engine\2019-01-03T08-13-26-03
Information: Program: HCK Execution engine launched.
Information: Action:
Using project definition file: \\<MachineA>\PDEF_XML\CsDeviceControl\DC_Win10_Pro_x64_PDEF_SINGLE_TEST.xml
```

Thanks for your time and any advice.

Ren

Answer (score 0):

I ended up circumventing the process by hosting the files on the remote machine.  CredSSP wasn't working and it seemed like it issue lived in double hop and the fact that the share lives on the machine invoking the command.  I was tired of trying to make it work.